# Selenium-webdriver 0.1.4 broken with Firefox 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, selenium, cucumber, webdriver

I'm having kind of a big problem that I need to solve pretty quickly, but I'm just not sure how.

Right now I've got an app that's stuck using the selenium-webdriver gem at v0.1.4.  I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and the Firefox Stable PPA. A few nights ago, Firefox forced their new v5.0, and now the Webdriver extension in Firefox is broken.  That basically means that when I run Cucumber tests, Firefox will launch, but it won't be able to do anything, since the Webdriver is disabled.

Now, I've been watching for days, and it looks like the folks over at Selenium have updated their 0.2.x release to be compatible with Firefox 5.  But I'm hesitant to upgrade what appears to be a significant version increase. I've tried downloading Firefox-4.0 from the FF website, but from what I can tell they just sneak it in as FF5 (every time I launch FF4 directly, it still launches FF5). I've also tried to use the Force Version feature in Synaptic, but FF4 isn't available there either.

I either need to find a hack to fix webdriver 0.1.4 or downgrade to FF4. Does anyone have any advice?

====================================

Edit: Some of the above was written in frustration amid a number of dependency issues, and a lot of it was from my own misunderstanding.  I meant no offense, and am kicking myself for not seeing was staring me right in the face. I've toned down my rant. Selenium and Firefox are solid products, and I'm just glad I got them working again.

Solved the problem by just upgrading to >= 0.2.2.  I thought the version jump from 0.1.x to 0.2.x indicated potential compatibility issues that I wasn't prepared to deal with at the time.

Comment: Why can't you upgrade to the latest version of the gem? Firefox 5 wasn't released when we did 0.1.4, and I'm not sure what you mean by "completely neglecting this support" - do you expect us to backport bug fixes and re-release every published gem?

Comment: Jarib, I apologize for this wording, and I'll change it. It was a misunderstanding of the versioning on my part. I didn't realize that 0.1.x and 0.2.x weren't drastic (i.e. possibly breaking api) version changes. I've been doing a lot of gem update tests lately and got kind of a haze as far as what version numbers meant amid a lot of other things breaking.  I thought that 0.1.x and 0.2.x were possibly different maintained versions of the same app, completely ignoring the version increments in between. A bit of selective blindness.  Sorry about that. Kudos to the solid gem, I meant no offense.

Comment: No problem. I bumped to 0.2.0 because we replaced the Chrome driver with a complete rewrite in that release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a post [here](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara/browse_thread/thread/415cac253e22b0e3?pli=1) by a user named jarra that appears to have directions for installing FF4 back to the mac and then forcing selenium to use FF4.

Comment: I ended up installing the updated gem, and I had been following that thread, but for some reason never saw anything past my original post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the extension was disabled due to incompatibility?

Then you can force compatibility by adding the entry extensions.checkcompatibility.5.0 to about:config, with value **false**. Restart Firefox. If the addon remains disabled, install MR Tech's Toolkit addon, restart Firefox, right-click on the addon, "enable incompatible addon" (or something else). After restarting, Webdriver should work fine.

Comment: In my about:config output, there is no item called extensions.checkcompatibility.5.0. MR Tech's Toolkit itself is not available for FF 5 so you cannot install it in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't exist, that's why my answer **bold**clearly told to add**bold** it. After adding the entry, you can install the MR Tech addon.